# Pass props to an axios get request

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-props

My intention is to get the weather data for the selected country, passing selectedCountry.capital to the query, so it is displayed the weather from current country capital when the data of a country is displayed.

```
useEffect(() => {

  axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=${selectedCountry.capital}`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
    } )

}, [])
```

First problem: I am not passing selectedCountry.capital to the query, since     console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital) returns undefined.

If I hardcode the query, I get a weather response.

```
useEffect(() => {

  axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=New York`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
    } )

}, [])
```

I also tried to pass it like this

```
useEffect(() => {

  axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=New York`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
    } )

}, [selectedCountry.capital])
```

[selectedCountry.capital]) I can log the capital. But it is some weird way to do it. And I can't display the weather data, since It will pass the selectedCountry.capital only after I select the country. There should be another way.

How do I pass selectedCountry.capital to the weather query?

Full code:
[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wind-9on0z?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
//setCountries is a function for setting the country's state
const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
//Filter
const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('')

//Update state with button
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('')

const [weather, setWeather] = useState('')
  
const hook = () => {
    console.log('effect')
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('promise fulfilled')
        setCountries(response.data)
        
      })
  }

  useEffect(hook,[])
/*   by default the effect is always run after the component has been rendered. In our case, however, we only want to execute the effect along with the first render.
  The second parameter of useEffect is used to specify how often the effect is run. If the second parameter is an empty array [], then the effect is only run along with the first render of the component. */

  console.log('render', countries.length, 'countries')
  console.log(countries)

/* weather */

useEffect(() => {
  if( selectedCountry.capital !== '' )
  {
    axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=${selectedCountry.capital}`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital" +selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
      
    } )
  }    
}, [selectedCountry.capital])





  //When button es clicked the state is set, and the state variable is used

  const renderCountryDetails = () => {
    return (
      selectedCountry && (
        <p key={selectedCountry.alpha2Code}>
       <p>   Capital: {selectedCountry.capital}.</p>
       <p>  Population:{" "}
          {selectedCountry.population}</p> 

          <p>
            <img src={selectedCountry.flag} style={{ width: '200px'}}/>
</p> 
        
<h3>Languages</h3>
<p>      {selectedCountry.languages.map(language => <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}

   <div>
          <h4>Weather</h4>
          <h5>temperature: {weather.temperature} Celisues</h5>
          <img src={weather.weather_icons[0]} alt='' />
          <h5>
            wind: {weather.wind_degree} mph direction {weather.wind_dir}
          </h5>
        </div>   

</p>



</p>


      )
    );
  };



const filteredCountries =
searchFilter.length === 1
? countries
: countries.filter(
(country) => country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1
)

//showCountries returns either a message or else the contents of filteredcountries array
const showCountries = () => {


if (filteredCountries.length > 10) {
return 'Too many matches, keep on typing'
}


if (filteredCountries.length > 0 
    && filteredCountries.length<10 
    && filteredCountries.length>1 ) 
    {
      return (
        <div>
          {filteredCountries.map((country) => (
            <p key={country.alpha2Code}>
              {country.name}
              {
                //Update stste when button is clicked, passing country as a prop to the state
                //onClick state is updated, causing the page to refresh and executing renderCountryDetails
                //that uses the set state (the country) to render the info.
                <button onClick={
                  () => setSelectedCountry(country)}>
                  show
                </button>
              }
            </p>
          ))}
          <div>{renderCountryDetails()}</div>
          <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    

    if (filteredCountries.length === 1) {
      return filteredCountries.map((country) =>

      
  <p key={country.alpha2Code}>
    <p>Capital: {country.capital}.
    <p> Population: {country.population} </p> 
    <h3>languages</h3>
                {country.languages.map(language => <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}

    <p><img src={country.flag} style={{ width: '200px'}}/>
    </p> 
    
    </p>
    </p>

  )
      }
    } 
     


const searchHandler = (e) => {
  //setSelectedCountry state is set to empty
  setSelectedCountry("");
setSearchFilter(e.target.value)
}

  return (
<div>

<div>
<h1>Countries</h1>
</div>
<div>
Type to find countries: 
<input onChange={searchHandler} />
<div>
{showCountries()}
</div>
</div>

</div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Edit:
I get the array data passing selectedCountry.capital, like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  if( selectedCountry.capital !== '' )
  {
    axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=${selectedCountry.capital}`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital" +selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
      
    } )
  }    
}, [selectedCountry.capital])
```

However, I can't acess to the array after it has been fetched, resulting on an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'temperature' of undefined
> Code updated

Comment: The reason is `selectedCountry` initial value is `''`, so the capital property is undefined. You need to set `selectedCountry` to some value as you are trying to call respective axios in useEffect initial rendering time. If it has dependency on all countries axios fetch, then you can move this axios call to the then of all countries axios call.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
useEffect(() => {

}, []);
```

This `useEffect` will run on component load and at that time `${selectedCountry.capital}` is blank.

To handle this issue try something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if( selectedCountry.capital} !== '' )
  {
    // Make your axios call here
  }    
}, [selectedCountry.capital]);
```

`selectedCountry.capital` is dependency so this effect will run on component load and every time `selectedCountry.capital` will change and on first time when this effect run we have a conditional check so axios request will not trigger.

Comment: It works for the part now ussefect gets the selectedCountry.capital, and it fetches the weather array data.
However, If I try to display the weather data, I get an error, since the weather data is not there yet.

If I add the code to display the weather data after the array has been fetched, it works.